# Can 'collections' be 'objects'?

Tags: ontology, terminology, set-theory, introduction-to-philosophy

Most things we call 'objects' are generally made up of other 'objects' can we consider a collection, such as a physical collection of objects as an 'object' itself?
If we have a 'collection' or an object made of several components, do we define it as 'one object' or as 'multiple objects' or as a singular 'collection'?

Then I ask if the converse is true, can we take an 'abstract' object and in fact have it as an abstract 'collection' that we can compose into different abstracts?

Comment: Everything can be described as a system; according to the Theory of Systems, a system is a set of interrelated parts, so every system is made of (sub)systems and every system is part of another system. Ergo, yes, any collection is an object (a computer is a set of electronic components), and any object is part of a collection (a network is a collection of computers).

Comment: What's this problem different than the standard philosophical problem of the universals?...

Comment: The book "Contemporary Metaphysics" by M. Jubien has a great chapter on parts and wholes.

Comment: @RodolfoAP so the ideas of saying there is 'one thing', 'one object' etc is really just our minds way of referring to what he see, can abstracts be given the same treatment, decomposed into a set of 'ideas' that encapsulate them?